# How to preserve data types of a particular key in JSON Object using GSON?

Tags: java, json, string, gson

I have my original JSON String like this in which I have key and value as shown below -

```
{
  "u":{
     "string":"1235"
  },
  "p":"2047935",
  "client_id":{
     "string":"5"
  },
  "origin":null,
  "item_condition":null,
  "country_id":{
     "int":3
  },
  "timestamp":{
     "long":1417823759555
  },
  "impression_id":{
     "string":"2345HH*"
  },
  "is_consumerid":true,
  "is_pid":false
}
```

As an example, one key is `"u"` and its value is -

```
{
    "string":"1235"
}
```

Similarly another key is `"country_id"` and its value is -

```
{
    "int":3
}
```

Now what I need to do is, I need to represent key value pair as shown below. If any value is string data type (like value for key `u`), then represent it's value in double quotes, otherwise don't represent it's value in double quotes. Meaning value of country_id won't be in String double quotes since it is an int.

```
"u": "1235"
"p": "2047935"
"client_id": "5"
"origin":null
"item_condition":null
"country_id": 3 // I don't have double quotes here around 3 since country_id was int that's why
"timestamp": 1417823759555
"impression_id": "2345HH*"
"is_consumerid": true
"is_pid": false
```

And then I need to make another json string which should look like this -

```
{
    "u": "1235",
    "p": "2047935",
    "client_id": "5",
    "origin":null,
    "item_condition":null,
    "country_id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1417823759555,
    "impression_id": "2345HH*",
    "is_consumerid": true,
    "is_pid": false
}
```

So I started my approach like this and came with below code -

```
    String response = "original_json_string";
    Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(response).getAsJsonObject();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> object : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
        if (object.getValue() instanceof JsonObject) {
            String data = object.getValue().toString();
            Map<String, Object> jsonIn = gson.fromJson(data, type);
            Map<String, Object> jsonOut = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            Set<String> keys = jsonIn.keySet();
            for (String key : keys) {
                Object value = jsonIn.get(key);
                if (value instanceof Map) {
                    Map<?, ?> mapValue = (Map<?, ?>) value;
                    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : mapValue.entrySet()) {
                        jsonOut.put(key, entry.getValue());
                    }
                } else {
                    jsonOut.put(key, value);
                }
            }

            // System.out.println(jsonOut);

            String json = gson.toJson(jsonOut);
            System.out.println(json);

        }
    }
```

Above code is working fine. Only thing which is not working is - when I try to serialize jsonOut map to a JSON, then some key values are not getting shown correctly. For example `country_id` and `timestamp` these two key values are wrong.

So right now my json is getting printed like this - You can see, value of `country_id` is 3.0 instead it should be 3. Similarly value of `timestamp` is 1.417823759555E12 instead it should be 1417823759555

```
{
    "u": "1235",
    "p": "2047935",
    "client_id": "5",
    "origin":null,
    "item_condition":null,
    "country_id": 3.0,              // this is different value
    "timestamp": 1.417823759555E12, // and this is different value
    "impression_id": "2345HH*",
    "is_consumerid": true,
    "is_pid": false
}
```

so ny new json should print out like this -

```
{
    "u": "1235",
    "p": "2047935",
    "client_id": "5",
    "origin":null,
    "item_condition":null,
    "country_id": 3,
    "timestamp": 1417823759555,
    "impression_id": "2345HH*",
    "is_consumerid": true,
    "is_pid": false
}
```

How can I do this and what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Presumably when GSON read the incoming data it used Double for everything.  To coerce to the desired types you would need to modify the logic for the `instanceof Map` case.  Basically, extract the key as well as the value, then have a `switch` on the key value to assign numerics to new types.

Comment: If at all possible, re-design JSON format -- it makes no sense to add redundant information like "string" in there -- value is already a String, so why add useless decoration?

Comment: @StaxMan Unfortunately I cannot change JSON format now. I need to stick with this format only. Any suggestions how can I do this?

Comment: I'd be guessing either doing two-pass processing (first into tree model, then converting it by walking into POJOs); or by custom reader/deserializer. I just dislike such formats in general and really wish there'd be more pushback for such unwieldy inefficient structures, this is why I suggested seeing if it could be changed. But I realize there are constraints -- it's just that without pushback, designers keep designing bad JSON formats. :-(

Comment: @StaxMan - It would certainly be silly to convert to POJOs when this close, and when I described how to get the desired output with a minor tweak to the above algorithm.  But I agree that the source JSON has an ugly layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gson, by default, uses `Double` for mapping any JSON number. Since you haven't explicitly stated the Java mapping (ie. you've used `Object`)

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
```

Gson will use its default.

Unless you specify the exact type, which seems to be difficult in your case since your JSON seems dynamic, you'll need to make the conversion yourself before adding it to your final serialized collection.

Comment: Thanks for useful information. Can you provide an example how would I do that manually?

Comment: In my code, I guess the line which is causing problem is this - `Map<String, String> jsonIn = gson.fromJson(data, type);`. When I try serialize JSON to a Map, it is getting converted to double values.

Comment: He has the exact type in the original JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Slight rewrite:

```
        for (String key : keys) {
            Object value = jsonIn.get(key);
            if (value instanceof Map) {
                Map<?, ?> mapValue = (Map<?, ?>) value;
                for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : mapValue.entrySet()) {
                    Double oldValue = (Double) entry.getValue();
                    Object newValue;
                    switch(entry.getKey()) {
                        case "int":
                            newValue = Integer.valueOf(oldValue.intValue());
                            break;
                        case "long":
                            newValue = Long.valueOf(oldValue.longValue());
                            break;
                        case "string":
                            newValue = oldValue;
                            break;
                        default:
                            newValue = "Error -- could not translate";
                    }
                    jsonOut.put(key, newValue);
                }
            } else {
                jsonOut.put(key, value);
            }
        }
```